How do I use `yq` to count the number of yaml documents present in multidocument yaml file that uses the `---` separator?
Given yaml file:
---
one: hey
---
two: you
---

How do I use yq to count the number of distinct yaml documents in the file?
yq ea '. as $item ireduce (0; . + 1)'
yields
3
3
3

and
yq e '. as $item ireduce (0; . + 1)'
yields
1
1
1

Not only can I not get the syntax quite right, I argue that, since the first three characters in the yaml file are --- and the last three are ---, my expectation is that there should only be two documents.

Check out 'document_index'

From the YAML specs: "YAML uses three dashes (“---”) to separate directives from document content. This also serves to signal the start of a document if no directives are present.", and if you're curious: "Three dots ( “...”) indicate the end of a document without starting a new one". As for mikefarah/yq, use the document_index (or di) keyword (see the manual); for kislyuk/yq, use the --slurp (or -s) option and the length keyword (manual).
